# Can an Angular schematic execute logic outside of the directory from where it ran

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-schematics, angular-devkit

I've created an Angular schematic that needs to create a bunch of files outside of the root directory i.e. `../../root`.

when trying to run the schematic locally I keep getting a CLI **warning**:

`The 'path' option in 'C:\Users\username\source\repos\test-schematic\src\test-schematic\schema.json' is using deprecated behaviour. 'workingDirectory' smart default provider should be use`

and CLI **error**:

`path /../ is invalid`

Using `'@angular-devkit/schematics'`:

```
const charts = apply(url('./files/charts'), [
  move(normalize(`../${_options.root}/${_options.project}-charts` as string)),
]);
```

Is there a way to create files outside of the directory from where the schematic got executed?

Comment: Could you provide the code related to the schematic function ?